# What is the practical use of bandwidth-delay product?

Tags: ethernet, network, networking, switching, bandwidth

It's given that the bandwidth-delay product defines the number of bits that can fill the link; while the sender can send (1+(2 * Propagation Time / Transmission Time)) units before getting acknowledged for the first unit. Can anyone help me to realize the practical implication the phenomenon of filling the link will imply? What can be the specific cases where (Bandwidth * Delay) should act as a constraint rather than (1+(2 * Bandwidth * Delay))? Where do I need (bandwidth * delay) and where (1+(2 * Propagation Time / Transmission Time))?